# How to fix this error: "attempt to index ? (a number value)"

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local questions={
    EN={
        Q1={"",""},
        Q2={"",""},
        Q3={"",""},
        Q4={"",""},
        Q5={"",""},
        Q6={"",""},
        Q7={"",""},
        Q8={"",""},
        Q9={"",""},
        Q10={"",""}
    },
    BR={
        Q1={"",""},
        Q2={"",""},
        Q3={"",""},
        Q4={"",""},
        Q5={"",""},
        Q6={"",""},
        Q7={"",""},
        Q8={"",""},
        Q9={"",""},
        Q10={"",""}
    },
    TR={
        Q1={"",""},
        Q2={"",""},
        Q3={"",""},
        Q4={"",""},
        Q5={"",""},
        Q6={"",""},
        Q7={"",""},
        Q8={"",""},
        Q9={"",""},
        Q10={"",""}
    }
}
local current_question = questions.EN.Q..math.random(1,10)[1]
```

I want to make the `current_question` variable return a random question from the `questions` table but it gives me an error; "attempt to index ? (a number value)"

Comment: You'd be better off having the `Q`'s be one array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the interpreter `Q..math.random(1,10)` is one string like this:

```
local current_question = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,10)][1]
```